# Unable to download mp3 songs from server

Tags: web-services, mp3

Here you can see there are two websites which stores some musics
http://songspkherodownload.com/Ankit%20Tiwari-SongspkHero.Com/
Other one is
http://madmusic.esy.es/files/msc/
They both stores song but when we are on first one, once the file is clicked it gets downloaded but on the other one it gets played in browser instead of downloading.
What's the issue with other one.

Comment: Your question is off-topic. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming, not for help downloading files from the Internet. But anyway, this behaviour is caused by the `Content-Type` HTTP headers served with these MP3 files. The site at madmusic serves MP3 files with a content type of `audio/mpeg`. Your browser knows how to handle files of this type, and plays them for you instead of downloading. On the other hand, songspkherodownload serves MP3 files with a content type of `application/octet-stream`. Your browser has no handler for files of this type, so it just downloads them instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage This question is perfectly on-topic for Stack Overflow.